# Azure storage Dll error while importing and exporting

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, dllimport, assembly-references

I have use this(https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) nuget package dll into my unity folder for accessing the my azure table and the data.
But unfortunately this is is causing the issue like not load dll.
The page it was mentioned the dll is deprecated and i cant find other dll which will replace this.
Is there any way i can sole this issue and get any new dll which will work with unity?
This is the error which i am getting during export:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That package is rather old. Please use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to access the table storage (the name implies it is only useable for Cosmos DB but that is not the case):

> This client library enables working with the Microsoft Azure CosmosDB Table API a**s well as Azure Table Storage.**

Comment: i have imported this dll, but getting an error message from unity after import it. assembly reference error.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message with as much detail as possible?

Comment: Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.OData.Core'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
                     Added the reference dll into my project, that dll have some dependency of other dll and its keep continuing.